# Why orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement is equal only on finite subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I had to prove that, if $U$ is a vector space and $S$ is a subspace, then $S =(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$. The thing is, $dim U < \infty$. I was wondering if $S =(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ does not happen in infinite spaces? Why is this?

Comment: It's because if $U$ is finite dimensional, then $S$ is always closed. This may not be the case if $U$ is infinite-dimensional. The theorem is then $\overline S =(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks, but may I ask what does it mean for $S$ to be closed?

Comment: Well, the complement is open in the topology on the space. More concretely, if $U$ is a normed space, then it's just like the situation in $\mathbb R$, that $S$ contains all its limit points. That is, if there is a sequence $x_n$ in $S$ that converges to some $x\in U$ then in fact $x\in S$.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: For example, let $U$ be the vector space of square-summable sequences (that is, all $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ with $\sum a_i^2<\infty$), let $S$ be the subspace of such sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms. Then $S^{\perp}$ has only the zero vector, and $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}=U\ne S$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks